# In-App Billing integration

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have to implement In-App billing so we can sell some content through our app.I have read documentation site but little bit confused about this.I have following queries.

```
1.How to integrate In-App billing 
2.The complete architecture of Billing system 
3.how will I get money of our content (It's process)
```

If someone knows it well please reply.I will really appreciate this thanks

Comment: Down voter write comment plz

Comment: look here a HowTo integrate in-app billing: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/how-to-integrate-in-app-purchase-billing-in-android.html  another tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Comment: HI @FeritCubukcuoglu Thanks It's really helpful can u plz explain how will we get money i mean complete architecture of billing process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all look here, if your country is supported:
   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324?hl=en&ref_topic=15867
2. Follow these steps in the [Administering In-App billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html)

**Important**: You must have a [Google Wallet](https://wallet.google.com/) merchant account to use the In-app Billing service on Google Play.

***Google Play Purchase Flow**

Google Play uses the same checkout backend service as is used for application purchases, so your users experience a consistent and familiar purchase flow.

To initiate a purchase, your application sends a billing request for a specific in-app product. Google Play then handles all of the checkout details for the transaction, including requesting and validating the form of payment and processing the financial transaction.
When the checkout process is complete, Google Play sends your application the purchase details, such as the order number, the order date and time, and the price paid. At no point does your application have to handle any financial transactions; that role is provided by Google Play.*

I hope this Information helps!!

Comment: Thanks it's really helpful Now i wanna know one thing tell me how can we get sold content amount

Answer (score 2):

Android provides a very good sample project called TrivialDrive where you can simulate buying gas.

Follow these steps in eclipse to import the project:
File>New>Other>Android Sample Project> Select android version > Select "TrivialDrive[Google play billing library]

It has clear instructions on how in app billing works + the points mentioned in answer from Ferit Cubukcuoglu

More on flow [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase)

Let me know if you need elaboration.